# Npgsql Replacing Hostname in the Connection String

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

I'm trying to connect to a Heroku PostgreSQL instance using the `npgsql` NuGet package. I've a problem with the connection string – **the hostname gets replaced with my computer's public IP** (see the screenshot below). An exception gets thrown in the `Open()` method of the `NpgsqlConnection` stating that the host doesn't exist. The rest of the parameters specified in the string (username, password and the database used) get recognized correctly.

[image: Screenshot – Server Hostname Replaced with Public IP]

I've tried using `Host`, `Server` and `server` instead of `host` but that doesn't seem to change anything. The database is up and running as I can connect to it using DataGrip with the same connection details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is from the database, not the library. It is saying that `pg_hga.conf` doesn't have an entry to allow your ip address to have access. You can read more about this file here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Apparently Heroku requires the connection to be SSL secured, which DataGrip seems to do by default but my code doesn't. Just leaving this here in case anyone comes across the same problem.